# 403 Server Error when adding Javascript to page using HTML Widget in Elementor

Tags: javascript, elementor

Using the HTML widget in Elementor Pro, I add a javascript tag to the page, hit update, and get a 403 error.

The javascript is a dynamic, simple sign up form that embeds properly.

I do not have any security plugins like WordFence that would be conflicting, and I have disabled all plugins just in case.

I have seen this: [Update button does not work](https://docs.elementor.com/article/185-the-update-button-does-not-work) but I don't have access to the site's files, so I can't increase the memory limit.

[Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6lkS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps in order to whitelist the Elementor plugin:

1. Go to Wordfence -> All Options
2. Scroll down until you see Whitelisted URLs
3. Put /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php for the URL
4. Select Param Type: POST Body for the dropdown
5. Put actions for the Param Name
6. Click Add
7. Click Save Changes in the top right corner

from [wordpress support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-get-a-403-error-when-inserting-a-tag-via-elementor/)

Comment: Im getting the same error but i havent installed the wordfence, what could be the possiblity?

Answer (score 1):

If You use Wordfence Follow @Luis Alvarado Day answer.
other plugin may have this option differently.

If you did not use any security plugin then maybe your cPanel have Security software like "ModSecurity". Go to the cPanel and disable for your domain.